# To find the Partial derivatives of $x$ and $y$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Given $f(x,y) = \int_x^y \! g(t) \, \mathrm{d}t.$

$g$ is continuous for all $t$.

I need  to find partial derivatives w.r.t $x$ and $y$.

Since no function $g$ is given, then i won't be able to integrate and compute partials. I feel i am missing some concept here needed to solve the question. Please Help me to fin what i am missing.

Thanks.

Comment: What you're missing is the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: @GitGud Can you show me complete solution

Comment: Taylor, it was a hint. Look for first fundamental theorem of calculus and your question would be easily solved.

Comment: @hvedrung Is this same as Leibniz Rule for Differentiation under Integral

Comment: Yes, a simple case of it.

Answer (score 2):

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:
$$f(x,y)=\int_x^y g(t) dt=G(y)-G(x)$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial G(y)}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial G(x)}{\partial x}$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial G(x)}{\partial x}=-g(x)$$

Similarly for the partial derivative w.r.t. $y$.